# Angular typescript convert string to number

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to convert a `string number` (an integer represented as a string. ex "12" ) to a `number`

**Model Class**

```
export class Person{
  FirstName :  string | undefined ;
  Telephone:  number | undefined ;

}
```

**TS file**

```
  console.log("Person" + JSON.stringify(this.person));
```

The JSON appears as

```
{
    "FirstName ": "hhhhh",
    "Telephone": "1478525",
}
```

The Telephone property is a number and I want it to appear as follows (without the ""_ :

```
{
    "FirstName ": "hhhhh",
    "Telephone": 1478525,
}
```

Approaches I took.

```
this.person.Telephone = parseInt(telephone);
```

Above didn't work, it shows the same number enclosed as a `string`. I also tried the following:

```
this.person.Telephone as number
```

both approaches didn't work. Can someone help me solve this ?

Error I get if I don't convert to a number:

> "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path:
> $.Telephone | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 18."

Comment: Yes. Dont convert telephone to a number. A telephone number is not a number, it should be represented by a string. A number is something numeric, if you are wanting to know is it a number or a string ask yourself if it would make sense to perform a numeric operation on it. Would you ever add a number to a telephone number or subtract from it or divide by it. What about numbers in countries that start with 0? Those would have a problem if you convert it to a number. In the Netherlands almost all mobile numbers start with 06.

Comment: I get an error if I don't convert. Please look at updated post for the error. I tried adding a number (as integer ) from postman when sending request to server and it works then. So I need to make it a pure Integer.

Comment: Ok @Igor Let's say it's not Telephone but, age. Because I have another property which also  has the same issue.

Comment: In that case `parseInt` is the way to go when you want to convert a string to a number. If you want more help you need to create an [mcve] because `"Above didn't work, "` is not descriptive enough as `this.person.Telephone = parseInt(telephone);` should work just fine.

Comment: just change your class definition for the telephone property to be a string not a number

export class Person{
  FirstName :  string | undefined ;
  Telephone:  string| undefined ;

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try this =>

```
let stringToNumberData = "123";
let numberValue = Number(stringToNumberData);
console.log(numberValue);
//Returns 123
```

OR

```
if(!isNaN(Number(stringToNumberData ))){
  let numberValue = Number(stringToNumberData );
  console.log(numberValue);
} else{
    console.log('Not a Number');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the standard javascript [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
this.person.Telephone = Number(telephone); 
console.log("Person" + JSON.stringify(this.person));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unary operator +

```
export class Person{
  FirstName :  string | undefined;
  Telephone:  number | undefined;
}
let person = new Person();
person.FirstName = "Name";
person.Telephone = 12345;
console.log(person);
person.Telephone = +"12345";
console.log(person);
```

Output:

```
Person { FirstName: 'Name', Telephone: 12345 }
Person { FirstName: 'Name', Telephone: 12345 }
```

PS: Use string as the data type for phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a number from a string, you can use this approach.

```
let person = {
name: "Some Name",
age: "45"
};

console.log('Person obj before modification ==>', person);

person.age = parseInt(person.age, 10);

console.log('Person object after modifying ==>', person);
```

Answer (score 0):

One scenario where the string to number conversion might be needed is while fetching the params from the activated route in Angular.
The easiest way is to append a + operator at the beginning.

```
constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }



ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];//convert param string to number if needed
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(id);
    this.actRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.server = this.serversService.getServer(+params['id']);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const stringValue: string = '341';
    const numberValue: number = +stringValue;
    // numberValue === 341
  }
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that `+""` evaluates to `0` whereas `parseInt("")` returns `NaN`.